# Java + X509: How get Certificates Revoked?

Tags: java, ssl, pki

Doing debugging in the X509 Certificate Validation Mechanism of Java I just wonder how certificates get revoked? By RFC 4158 (and PKI related documentation) I learned that each CA (or Party providing Trust Anchors) can issue a CRL (Certification Revocation List).

Is Java downloading CRLs on its own or just will provide updated information with each (minor) version I update?

What options exist for a custom infrastructure (is it best practice to provide once own (global) TrustManager?)

Answer (score 1):

> Doing debugging in the X509 Certificate Validation Mechanism of Java I
>   just wonder how certificates get revoked? By RFC 4158 (and PKI related
>   documentation) I learned that each CA (or Party providing Trust
>   Anchors) can issue a CRL (Certification Revocation List).

The certificates include as part of their information how to check revocation, normally a CRL (Certificate Revocation List) or online service OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol)

A certification service provider (CA) revoke a certificate by including it in the CRL and its OCSP service. When the customer wants to check revocation of a certificate download the CRL to check or performs an OCSP request

> Is Java downloading CRLs on its own or just will provide updated
>   information with each (minor) version I update?

No, Java allows you to check certificate revocation, but does not itself

> What options exist for a custom infrastructure (is it best practice to
>   provide once own (global) TrustManager?)

Java has its own structure to establish a truststore using keystore files (JKS or PKCS12 format). The default is jre/lib/security/cacerts. The truststore will be checked in https connections for example

It is good practice to use the tools provided by the system, unless you need to improve functionality. Explain your use case and I could be more specific

Comment: It was a question raised during debugging. Bascially the problem was a 3rd party tool came with its own jks and I had suddently three different trust stores used differently. I just wondered if Java catches up with revocations by adding additional information with each update they publish.

Comment: Probably the tool use its own truststore replacing the JDK cacerts (usually to add trusted certificates). There is no any Java process that checks revocation of these truststores. In this case it might be advisable to unify into one central JKS. Especially for renovations. But if the tool frequently releases updates, you must have work to unify (via script for example)

Comment: I do overwrite the truststore by intention the fun was that I really had multiple truststore.

Comment: If you do not control the other tool, really you do not have too many options ...